# Extract a part of text value from response and store it in a variable by using junit/reassured?

Tags: rest-assured, junit5

I need to test an api endpoint where response of the endpoint will be like this

Response:

```
 {
    "items": [
       {
           "url": "http://www.localhost.com:8080/user?id=19909090"
       }
    ]
}
```

I want to store the id value that is `19909090` to a variable. Can you please suggest some solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JsonPath](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath) to read the value of `url`.

For example:

```
String url = from(json).get("$.items[0].url");
```

And then use `java.net.URI` to extract the query parameter value.

For example:

```
URI uri = URI.create(url);

String[] params = uri.getQuery().split("=");

// prints out 19909090
System.out.println(params[1]);
```

Comment: Hi @glytching, yes. I have checked the mark. Thanks for the info.